# Generating 2D array in Bash with unknown dimension

Tags: command-line, scripts

just wondering if it's possible to generate a 2D array if the dimension is not known prior to user input. For example if user input 2 2 on the commandline the shell will generate a 2D array base on that? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` is an interpreted language, and it doesn't need to know how much memory to allocate in advance.

So it's possible to dinamically initialize a new array without having declared it or to expand an already declared array to add more entries, however it's not possible to use multidimensional arrays.

However this can be faked: since you didn't provide an exact task to accomplish, I'll provide a `bash` script example which shows how to fill in an user-defined `m x n` table with random numbers (which are not really random, since each column will always have the same number on all its rows in each run, but this is not relevant to the question) and print it (simplified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16487733/4316166) Stack Overflow answer):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array
read -p 'm: ' m
read -p 'n: ' n
for ((i=0; i<m; i++))
do
    for ((j=0; j<n; j++))
    do
        a[${i},${j}]=$RANDOM
    done
done
for ((i=0; i<m; i++))
do
    for ((j=0; j<n; j++))
    do
        echo -ne "${a[${i},${j}]}\t"
    done
    echo
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a 1D array and read all numbers into a 1D array at runtime. After knowing the dimension, you could process the 1D array "like a 2D array".

For instance, suppose 1D array contains

```
[1, 5, 9, 11]
```

If we really want

```
[[1,5], [9,11]]
```

as our array such that the index 0 is [1,5] then you could do something like this to access [1,5] (pos = 0)

#### pseudocode

```
for i in 0:(pos*dim + dim-1)  
    echo arr[i]
```

to access [9,11] (pos = 1)

```
for i in pos*dim:(pos*dim + dim - 1)
    echo arr[i]
```

Hopefully this makes some sense. Really a 2D array is sort of a 1D array.

Comment: [More info on arrays](http://www.tecmint.com/working-with-arrays-in-linux-shell-scripting/)